# Not retrieving nodes from XML package in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'm extracting nodes from an XML file with R, using the *XML* package.

Unfortunately I got the impression that R doesn't recognize single tags, that is tag in this structure

```
<event currentPlaytime="600000" score_away="0"
score_home="0" tickerstateid="1" tickerstate="Not started"
minute="10" event_code="Players introduction" event_code_id="171"
event_number="5" matchid="210941"/>
```

I'm using for example

```
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(file, encoding = "UTF-8")
xpathApply(doc, "event", xmlGetAttr, "matchid")
```

but I got no results.

For a normal `XML` where the file is ended by `<\match>` for example, everything works.

The complete file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<event_list status="event" replytype="error" timestamp="1441886226356" xmlns="http://rball.com/eventpusher/data/xmltcpbeans">
<event matchid="269679" event_number="0" event_code_id="514" event_code="Scout in stadium" timestamp="1357486150967" minute="10" tickerstate="Not started" tickerstateid="1" score_home="0" score_away="0" currentPlaytime="600000" clockRunning="false"/>
<event matchid="269679" event_number="1" event_code_id="517" event_code="Transmission online" timestamp="1357486166310" minute="10" tickerstate="Not started" tickerstateid="1" score_home="0" score_away="0" currentPlaytime="600000" clockRunning="false"/>
</event_list>
```

Comment: Simply change XPath. Either full path `/root/event` or `//event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your xpath expression. I don't have your actual data but if if I run your code as

```
library(XML)
q <- '<event  currentPlaytime="600000" score_away="0" score_home="0" tickerstateid="1" tickerstate="Not started" minute="10" event_code="Players introduction" event_code_id="171" event_number="5" matchid="210941"/>'
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(q , encoding = "UTF-8")
xpathApply(doc, "/event", xmlGetAttr, "matchid")
```

then it'll print

```
> xpathApply(doc, "/event", xmlGetAttr, "matchid")
[[1]]
[1] "210941"
```

(note the xpath is `/event`, ie. begins with `/`)

Similarly, for two nodes (now wrapped in `root` node):

```
library(XML)
q <- '<event  currentPlaytime="600000" score_away="0" score_home="0" tickerstateid="1" tickerstate="Not started" minute="10" event_code="Players introduction" event_code_id="171" event_number="5" matchid="210941"/>'
q <- paste('<root>',q,'<event matchid="210942" />','</root>')
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(q , encoding = "UTF-8")
xpathApply(doc, "/root/event", xmlGetAttr, "matchid")
```

will print

```
> xpathApply(doc, "/root/event", xmlGetAttr, "matchid")
[[1]]
[1] "210941"

[[2]]
[1] "210942"
```

UPDATE March 9th 2016: Your XML now has namespace defined, so you need to use it:

```
library(XML)

q <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event_list status="event" replytype="error" timestamp="1441886226356" xmlns="http://rball.com/eventpusher/data/xmltcpbeans">
<event matchid="269679" event_number="0" event_code_id="514" event_code="Scout in stadium" timestamp="1357486150967" minute="10" tickerstate="Not started" tickerstateid="1" score_home="0" score_away="0" currentPlaytime="600000" clockRunning="false"/>
<event matchid="269679" event_number="1" event_code_id="517" event_code="Transmission online" timestamp="1357486166310" minute="10" tickerstate="Not started" tickerstateid="1" score_home="0" score_away="0" currentPlaytime="600000" clockRunning="false"/>
</event_list>'

ns <- c(ns="http://rball.com/eventpusher/data/xmltcpbeans")
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(q , encoding = "UTF-8")
xpathApply(doc, "/ns:event_list/ns:event", xmlGetAttr  , "matchid", namespaces = ns)
```

produces

```
> xpathApply(doc, "/ns:event_list/ns:event", xmlGetAttr  , "matchid", namespaces = ns)
[[1]]
[1] "269679"

[[2]]
[1] "269679"
```

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion on the file I uploaded but it doesn't work, maybe I'm missing something else

Comment: Thank you! Potentially is there a way to automate the namespace capture? (if for example every file has got a different namespace)

Comment: you could try `doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(q , encoding = "UTF-8")
getDefaultNamespace(doc)[[1]]$uri`